# Permission Denied cPanel or PHP file upload

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, centos, cpanel

I am trying to upload a file through cpanel or wordpress admin panel, but cpanel shows permission denied and wordpress requires ftp access (probably for the same reason). What may be the cause of this?

The public_html directory contains files that were copied from public folder of another server via rsync to /home/somename and then I ran cp command to move these files to public_html. And now, all this is happening. Before cp, there was previous version of website that was working fine.

I'm using Centos 6.3 with Apache

Comment: may be the file permission ? Did you try file permission to **755** ?

Comment: yes. every dir is 755 already.

Comment: Try changing dir to **777** then, just for testing purpose.

**777: Files with permissions set to 777 are readable, writeable, and executable by everyone. Don’t use this set of permissions, for security reasons, on your web server unless absolutely necessary.**

Comment: already tried 777. no success :(

Comment: I would highly advise against setting web directories to 777

Comment: What distribution of linux are you running?

Comment: Updating my answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Likely ownership issues.

For Centos 6 the default group for Apache is `apache`

Go to your webroot, and set the permissions to `chown -R apache:apache *`

Then make sure to set the permissions 0755

You may be better served by creating a new group and adding both yourself and apache to it.  Then assigning the permissions to `apache:<your new group>`

Comment: How to check and modify apache's group?

Comment: What is meant by "add yourself"? Does it mean the username I used for cpanel login? I do everything over SSH & SCP using root, and I think rsync also used root, and the same was also used when copied files to webroot.

Comment: You'll need to do some researching on user security.  I'd recommend: https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups

Comment: The answer above should however solve your immediate issue, with reasonable security.

Comment: I have tried `chown -R apache:apache *` and changed permission of everything within public_html to 0755 (and later 0775) but none is working. :(

Comment: When I upload to `public_html`, it works. But, when I try to upload to `public_html/wp-content`, it fails.\